# C++ terminate a thread without having acces to the function executed in the thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua, c++14, infinite-loop

I'm making a script handlers in C++14. I get function body in a lua script, that is suppose to be given by a client ( I use interpreter Sol/lua ),  and exectute it in a thread.
So my problems is if the client put a infinite loop (while true) in his script, I should be able to stop/kill the thread after 3 seconds.

I tryed with  and detach() but the infinite thread keep running during the entire rest of my programme.
Without detach(), SIGABRT is send and stop everything at the end of my scope.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

//function that i don't know the content.
//In the worst case, it's an infinite loop.
void infinitClientFunction() {
    while (true) {}
}

void callfunc() {
   std::thread t(infiniteClientFunction);
   t.detach();

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3500));
   // I want t terminated/kill/stop here (if it is infinite).
}


int main(){
   callfunc();
   // But t still exist here.

   /*
   rest of my program.
   ...
   */
}
```

That's doesn't seem complicated but I'm stuck.
Please help me.
Have a nice day.

(EDIT)
To specify, infiniteClientFunction is given by the client (by interpretting Lua Script but this is not the point).
So if the client use a correct syntax and lexic but give an unlogic function, I should be able to stop it after a some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicol Bolas said, "C++ has no mechanism to kill threads." That's because there is no *safe* way to kill a thread in any language or in any OS. You can never be sure that, at the moment when the thread is killed, it hasn't left something in a bad state—e.g., left a mutex locked, left a data structure in an invalid state—that will prevent the rest of your program from functioning as it should.

Running foreign code in your application always is a tricky proposition. The first step you can take toward doing it safely is to run the foreign code in a child process. Killing a process is much safer than killing a thread.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no mechanism to kill threads; OS's may, but you'll have to use their platform-specific functionality.

However, Lua has [debug hooks](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_sethook) that can be used to call into your code after a certain number of Lua instructions have been executed. You can use that debug hook to terminate the thread if too much time has passed since Lua execution began. You could throw a C++ exception if you build Lua as C++ (which makes it safe-ish to throw exceptions through Lua code).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an atomic global boolean:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_bool stop = false;

void infiniteClientFunction() {
    while (true) {
        if (stop) return;
    }
}

void callfunc() {
   std::thread t(infiniteClientFunction);
   t.detach();

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3500));
   stop = true;
}


int main(){
   callfunc();

   /*
   rest of my program.
   ...
   */
}
```

Comment: The Client fonction cannot contains your stop variable.

Comment: why not? what's the problem? I think this is the fastest and easiest method

Comment: @Tugamer89 The premise of the question is that the function run by the thread is not modifiable.

Comment: @rançois-andrieux the edit is made after my post(s) C:

Comment: @Bobuse can't you add `if (stop) return;` at the end of the translated code?

Comment: Yes I could but where is the interest if my thread is looping before the if (stop) return;